# MariaDB - update column with constant depending on another column values

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, mariadb

Lets assume I have table named **mytable** and this it looks-like this:

[image]

I want to be able to update all the records in **p6** column adding to the 39 but ONLY for the rows that has different **p2** values. In other words the result table should look-like this:

[image]

I colored the **p6** rows yellow to show where it should not move because all **p2** cells which are grey are the same value.
Green **p6** rows should grow because **p2** grows also so I add +39 to all of them. The last 13th row in example is again yellow because **p2** on 12 row = **p2** on 13 row.

With help of *Gordon Linoff* I managed to do something like that:

```
update mytable join
       (select mytable.*,
               (lag(p6) over(ORDER BY dt) +
                (case when lag(p2) over (order by dt) <> p2 then 39 ELSE 0 end)
               ) as new_p6
        from mytable
       ) tt
       on tt.id = mytable.id 
    set mytable.p6 = tt.new_p6
    where new_p6 <> mytable.p6;
```

But it is not updating as expected. Can you help me do it?

UPDATE WITH DATA:

```
id  dt  p2  p6
3   11.2.2021 15:45 536107.56   0
4   11.2.2021 15:50 536107.56   0
5   11.2.2021 15:55 536107.56   0
6   11.2.2021 16:00 536107.56   0
7   11.2.2021 16:05 536107.56   0
8   11.2.2021 16:10 609103.75   39
9   11.2.2021 16:15 609129.81   78
10  11.2.2021 16:20 609155.94   117
11  11.2.2021 16:25 609181.81   156
12  11.2.2021 16:30 609208.06   195
13  11.2.2021 16:35 609208.06   195
```

Comment: please post your data as text & not an image

Comment: updated with data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to enumerate the changes and multiply by 39, then you want somewhat different logic:

```
update mytable join
       (select tt.*,
               sum(case when p2 <> prev_p2 then 1 else 0 end) over (order by dt) as cnt
        from (select tt.*,
                     lag(p2) over (order by dt) as prev_p2
              from mytable tt
             ) tt
       ) tt
       on tt.id = mytable.id 
    set mytable.p6 = cnt * 39
    where cnt > 0;
```

Comment: I add 39, I am not multiplying it

Comment: @BorislavStefanov . . . You are multiplying it by the count.  It is the same thing.

Comment: Yes, agree. Thanks!